# Pysnmp Command responder wrapper

Tags: python, ubuntu, pysnmp

I want to develop simple pysnmp command responder to listen to my test instrument device, get requests came from the device and replace them with my own command (Telnet command)in my host PC (Ubuntu) and send it to evaluation board. In the past there was also support SNMP on HOST, I want to just keep the structure of exists PLUGIN on device and change only the Host side.

Please do not ask me why I do it that way.
I have prepared MIB file that works with the device in SNMP. PLUGIN installed on device knows how to work and send the MIB OID with the OID I know and according to the request need to replace by command of my own command on host PC.
Please see the flow for example get frequency from evaluation board:

> Plugin in device send command to get frequency (MIB OID): 
>   1.3.6.1.4.1.55555.1.1.5.1.1.2.1
>
> Listen to Device (SNMPv1 port 161), get request(1.3.6.1.4.1.55555.1.1.5.1.1.2.1) for frequency from device and replace it in local PC Host(Ubuntu): get_frequency_mycommand_telnet

How to do it in the most simple with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest you basing your script on [this example](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py).

You could implement your `telnet` communication [inside](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py#L44) the `__call__()` of your custom [MIB object instance](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py#L29). Make sure to set proper [OID](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py#L30) to make this object SNMP-addressable.

Also, add support for SNMP SET operation and probably pass incoming value into the `__call__()` or other method you may want to implement.

You may want to scratch [IPv6 support](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py#L148) if you do not need it.

Keep in mind that with this implementation `__call__()` is blocking so no other SNMP queries would be processed until `__call__()` is done. You could enhance it towards higher performance and concurrency by making your telnet client asynchronous.

Comment: [link]@Ilya Etingof,Thanks for the detailed answer, indeed I try to base my implementation on your link example. I'm almost no experience with working in-depth with SNMP. Do you intend to use: errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    setCmd(SnmpEngine(), ... ) Please, can you get an example of how to implement the SET command.

Comment: [link](@Ilya Etingof),How can I import my MIB to your example script?

Comment: For general understanding of SNMP I'd refer you [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/snmp-design.html). SET command examples could be seen [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/modifying-variables.html). To make pysnmp loading specific MIB file, you should point it to a directory/URL where it could find the MIB you refer to and all its dependencies. That can be done as shown [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-asn-1-mib-path).